# How can I force a bundle install on OpenShift Online when my RAILS_ENV is set to development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openshift, development-environment, bundle-install

I have a Rails app on OpenShift Online that I'm trying to setup with *RAILS_ENV*=**development** as opposed to the default env of **production**. The idea being later on I'll add test, staging and production domains.

My problem is that because the env is set to **development** the OpenShift process that runs when I do a *git push* says it's skipping "bundle install":

```
remote: NOTE: Skipping 'bundle install' because running in development mode.
```

I got it to do the *bundle install* by setting *RAILS_ENV* to production **temporarily**.

### Is there a way to **force** a *bundle install* in the OpenShift Online environment when running in **development mode**?

**UPDATE:** 

Tried forcing a *bundle install* via *.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build*. Getting **Gemfile syntax error** during *pre_build* hook. *Gemfile* works locally and on OpenShift when using RAILS_ENV = production.

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

### OpenShift Online changes:

# Fix the conflict with the system 'rake':
gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.6'

# Iron.io gems
gem 'iron_mq'
#gem 'iron_worker_ng'

# Support for databases and environment.
# Use 'sqlite3' for testing and development and mysql and postgresql
# for production.
#
# To speed up the 'git push' process you can exclude gems from bundle install:
# For example, if you use rails + mysql, you can:
#
# $ rhc env set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development test postgresql"
#

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'minitest'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'thor'
end

# Add support for the MySQL
group :development, :production, :mysql do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

### / OpenShift changes

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

### .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a simple script and will be executed on your CI system if
# available.  Otherwise it will execute while your application is stopped
# before the build step.  This script gets executed directly, so it
# could be python, php, ruby, etc.

if [[ "$RUBY_VERSION" == "1.8" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: This quickstart is not compatible with Ruby 1.8"
  echo "ERROR: Please use ruby-1.9 or ruby-2.0 application type."
  exit 1
fi

if [[ "$RAILS_ENV" == "development" ]]
then
  echo "Forcing bundle install for environment: $RAILS_ENV"

  pushd $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo > /dev/null
  bundle install --path ./vendor/bundle
  popd > /dev/null
fi
```

### Output from "git push" to OpenShift Online app

```
remote: Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Ruby cartridge in development mode, skipping stop...
remote: Force clean build enabled - cleaning dependencies
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 5c3182d
remote: Forcing bundle install for environment: development
remote: Gemfile syntax error:
remote: /var/lib/openshift/540306395973ca6dc30006bc/app-root/runtime/repo/Gemfile:56:
remote: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
remote: gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
remote:                                        ^
remote: Building Ruby cartridge
remote: NOTE: Skipping 'bundle install' because running in development mode.
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is a65ea3ad
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: NOTE: The 'rake assets:precompile' is disabled when Ruby is in development mode.
remote: bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
remote: /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-0.9.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 540306395973ca6dc30006bc (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'deploy' for 540306395973ca6dc30006bc application pvcentral)
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
To ssh://540306395973ca6dc30006bc@pvcentral-pervasivdev.rhcloud.com/~/git/pvcentral.git/
   8d74e27..5c3182d  master -> master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I was able to **force** a *bundle install* with **RAILS_ENV=development** by doing two things:

1. Modified the **pre_build** *action hook* to execute "bundle install" with the correct version of ruby and environment context
2. Added the **force_clean_build** *marker*

NOTE: My app was created using the Rails 4 (4.1.4) and **Ruby 2.0** quickstart.

What I tried above after the suggestion to add "bundle install" to an action hook (turns out pre_build is the correct one to modify) was okay except executing as:

bundle install --path ./vendor/bundle

results in a weird Gemfile syntax error on 'sdoc'.

I noticed that the **deploy** *action hook* included code to source a couple of files to set the ruby version and execution context. And also executed "bundle" as:

```
ruby_with_nodejs_context "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
```

After adding the "right" execution context (see below), the Gemfile syntax error disappeared. Finally, I had to add the force_clean_build marker because without it I was getting errors:

```
remote: Building Ruby cartridge
remote: Restoring previously bundled RubyGems
remote: NOTE: You can commit .openshift/markers/force_clean_build to force a clean bundle
remote: ERROR: You need to remove the ".bundle" directory from your GIT repository.
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/54077e9a5973ca2e6900096f/ruby
```

### .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build

```
source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH
source ${OPENSHIFT_RUBY_DIR}/lib/ruby_context

pushd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} >/dev/null
if [[ -f .openshift/markers/force_clean_build && "$RAILS_ENV" == "development" ]]
then
  echo "bundle install --path ./vendor/bundle"
  ruby_with_nodejs_context "bundle install --path ./vendor/bundle"
fi
popd > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an action hook to run bundle install.  Try this article: https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications look at the Customizing OpenShift's Build Process section.

Comment: I've tried running "bundle install" from both the build and pre_build action_hooks, but it's giving me the error: Bundler::Gemfile Not Found. I'm running "bundle install --path $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo/vendor/bundle" (copying from a successful bundle install when the environment was "production". I've even tried doing a popd into the $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo, where the Gemfile is, but  no luck. Do you have any ideas on what directory I should be in to get bundle to run?

Comment: I think you need to use the location of your Gemfile.lock which should be $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo ?

Comment: Running in $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo bundle was able to find the Gemfiles, but gave me an error on the 'sdoc' gem. And that came with the quickstart so I'm not sure what to do about that. It's giving a syntax error on that line, but I don't have an issue running bundle install locally--or on OpenShift if my env is production. And the "gem 'sdoc'" line isn't in a specific environment group.

Comment: Thanks for your help @developercorey! Files added above.